# Only the first mail have information on a for loop Mail::send Laravel

Tags: laravel, loops, email, mail-sender

I have a hello world template and I'm trying to send emails with this template in a for loop, I receipt the three mails but only the first mail shows the "hello world" and the other are empty. HELP!!!

```
function testMail(Request $request) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        $data = array();
        Mail::send('preview', $data, function($message) {
            $message->from('test@gmail.com');
            $message->to('test@gmail.com')->subject('Bla test: ');
        });
    }
}
```

**Note**: I will send different content to different emails. That's why I'm not making an array.

Comment: I can't see any "hello world" in your code

Comment: Thank you. You made me check my html code and I found the mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I never thought that the problem was on my template. The "include_once"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<body id="body">
      <?php include_once 'components/invoice_template.php';?>
</body>
</html>
```

For this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<body id="body">
      <?php include 'components/invoice_template.php';?>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that the include_once only works once. xD